# What is the correct way to be using the Node.js MySQL Library?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Currently I am playing around with the MySQL library in Node.js however I have a question about the correct/most efficient way to be using this library.

According to w3schools the correct way to make a single query is to use code like this

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

However, say I wanted to make multiple queries which would be executed by an event for example how would I handle this? Should I create an "initialise" function which is executed as soon as the program runs such as this?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var database;

//Initialise database
function setupDatabase() {
    database = mysql.createConnection({ 
        host: token.host,
        user: token.user,
        password: token.password,
        database: token.database,
        port: token.port
    });
}

//Imagine this could be called at any time after execution
function event() {
    if(database != null) {
        database.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            database.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(result);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And also do I have to connect to the database each time I make a query or can I add the "database.connect" call to my setupDatabase function such as this?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var database;

//Initialise database
function setupDatabase() {
    database = mysql.createConnection({ 
        host: token.host,
        user: token.user,
        password: token.password,
        database: token.database,
        port: token.port
    });

    if(database != null) {
        database.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    }
}

//Imagine this could be called at any time after execution
function event() {
    if(database != null) {
        database.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
}
```

My main concern is that calling the con.connect function every single time I make a query would be slow and although these are asynchronous I want to be using the correct/most efficient way possible. Feel free to correct me on any mistakes with the last two code snippets I have only tested the first one so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make database connection only once per application livetime (unless you have disconnects). Then you may have as much queries as you want.

Just put database connection routine somewhere in sepparate file and then require it in your applicatin initialisation step.

```
// mysql.js
const mysql = require('mysql');
module.exports = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});
```

Or require it anywhere you need database connection - it will return connected database object without reruning that code again and again.

```
// inex.js
const databse = require('./mysql')
database.query("SELECT * FROM customers")
```

Comment: So I just have to make the database.connect call once during runtime and i'm good until the program ends?

Comment: @Hamish yes. You connect to database and then work with it sending as much queries as you can send and it can handle ).

Answer (score 1):

I created a file which include a function that holds a pool and handles the connection to the database like this

```
let _this = {};
let POOL = null;

function getPool() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(POOL != null) {
            resolve(POOL);
        } else {
            //create connection pool
            POOL = connectionPool;
            resolve(POOL);
        }
    });
}

function closePool(){
    // close pool here
}

_this.getPool = getPool;
_this.closePool = closePool;

module.exports = _this;
```

Now you can call `getPool()` and will recive a pool of connections where you can execute your queries with.